# Check if that object property exists in the array

Tags: javascript

I have the following dataset

```
data=[{name: "hk", age:21, gender:"M"}, {name: "kk", age:31, gender:"M"},{name: "tk", age:11, gender:"F"}]
```

How could I test whether or not there is a person name `"hk"` and index of the found object.

I have checked with the following code, but it does not work.

```
data.hasOwnProperty("hk")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd have to iterate through the array and check each object for that

```
function hasName(prop, value, data) {
    return data.some(function(obj) {
        return prop in obj && obj[prop] === value;
    });
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/45wsq4pg/)

---

#### EDIT:

if you want to return the index instead, one has to use a loop that keeps track of the index, something like `forEach` instead

```
function hasName(prop, value, data) {
    var result = -1;
    data.forEach(function(obj, index) {
        if (prop in obj && obj[prop] === value) {
            result = index;
            return false;
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/45wsq4pg/2/)

Comment: Thanks adeneo, it works and quite easy to use. I will mark as an answer when SOF allows me.

Comment: How could I get index of the found object ?

Answer (score 5):

Try (like [indexOf](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp)):

```js
var data=[{name: "hk", age:21, gender:"M"}, {name: "kk", age:31, gender:"M"},{name: "tk", age:11, gender:"F"}]

function exists(name){
    var item, i = 0;
    while(item = data[i++])
        if(item.name == name) return --i
    return -1
}

alert("Exists tk? - Index: " + exists("tk")); //-1: not exists
```

Comment: Is there any built in method in javascript? rather than using while condition?

Comment: Yes, you can use `some` in a array, I used a loop since some still not supported in some browsers. It is even faster

Comment: How could I get index of the found object ?

Comment: Updated  `return index`: To check if not exists, the value returns -1. Equivale to [indexOf](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp)

Comment: Btw, I found that a regular `for (var i = 0, n = data.length; i != n; ++i)` operates faster than evaluating the array element each time.

Comment: @Jack, yes, you also save a few bytes :p