# Check if value exists in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I have an array of objects like this:

```
"localValues" : [
    {
        "localValId" : "e3rQACssGkfp9zsue",
        "localProductCode" : "271102502",
        "localMembersPrice" : 7814.090000000001,
        "localProductDescription" : "11R225 146/143L H DUN SP384 FM        TL",
        "fetPr" : "29.39",
        "invPrice" : "353.85"
    },
    {
        "localValId" : "NxtmZngRpGY56grkW",
        "localProductCode" : "290132910",
        "localMembersPrice" : "300",
        "localProductDescription" : "215/70R16 99S     DUN GRNDTRK ST20 BSWTL",
        "fetPr" : "",
        "invPrice" : "136.72"
    },
    {
        "localValId" : "WXLiCMJMixndtQtqZ",
        "localProductCode" : "271102502",
        "localMembersPrice" : "444",
        "localProductDescription" : "11R225 146/143L H DUN SP384 FM        TL",
        "fetPr" : "29.39",
        "invPrice" : "353.85"
    }];
```

Is there a way I can check if a new `localProductCode` already exists in the localValues array?

Thank you.

Comment: I want to point out that is not a nested array, but an array of objects.

Comment: What do you mean by *"new `localProductCode`"*?

Comment: @user1547174, same question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30720676/1074519

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try:

```
function isExisted(localValues, localProductCode) {
    for (var i = 0; i < localValues.length; ++i) {
        if (localValues[i].localProductCode == localProductCode) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to find the index of coincidence (like **[indexOf](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp)**)

```
Array.prototype.indexOfObj = function(key, value){
    for(var i = 0; i < this.length;) 
        if(this[i++][key] === value) return --i
    return -1
}

Items.localValues.indexOfObj("localValId", "NxtmZngRpGY56grkW"); //1
Items.localValues.indexOfObj("localValId", "WXLiCMJMixndtQtqZ"); //2
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wZVanG/v77pdo8q/)**